# How to setup Domain Driven Design (DDD) in a Laravel application (Recommendation need)

Tags: php, laravel

How to implement DDD artitecture in Laravel application, where to put entities, how to make relationship between multiple domain.

Comment: Awesome question but unfortunately SO is not the right place for the question :(

Comment: Actually i need some suggestion about this topic.

Comment: The difficulty I can see is that this question is quite a broad topic, which (not sure) may also involve a certain amount of opinion.  Both these reasons make having a definitive answer rather difficult and therefore usually off-topic for SO.